# JavaScript - Improve recursive loop which returns a value according to a single condition

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a method that takes as parameter an array of several depth (`group`) and a name as a string (`currentFilterName`)

```
checkFilterValue(group, currentFilterName) {
  group.forEach((element, index) => {
    if (element.children) {
      if (element.name === currentFilterName) {
        this.returnedValue = element.value
      } else {
        this.checkFilterValue(element.children || this.filtersConfig[index + 1], currentFilterName)
      }
    } else {
      if (element.name === currentFilterName) {
        this.returnedValue = element.value
      }
    }
  })
}
```

The depth levels are the `element.children` , being the goal is to return the `element.value`, at each turn if the element has a depth level I first check if`element.name === currentFilterName` if it is the case I would like returned the `element.value` if it is not the case I return the method evening with the next element.children if there is otherwise the original tables with the next index`this.filtersConfig [index + 1]`, if the element has no depth I simply check if`element.name === currentFilterName` and I return to `element.value`

The problem I have is that the method is a little verbose, how can we simplify it with an elegant writing?

Comment: Are you sure that the line `this.returnedValue = element.value` line runs? Can you give an example of an input?

Comment: @CertainPerformance that was the problem, I changed the question, I would like to improve it with a more elegant writing

Comment: Please note that in your code `this.filtersConfig[index + 1]` will never be evaluated because `element.children` is always truthy at that place.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can recursively go through your data to find a desired value based on the `filterName`

The issue with `forEach` is that you can't exit early, but you can with a `for` loop. You can use `break;` and `continue;` in a `for` loop to either exit early, or skip over an iteration.

```js
function checkFilterValue(data, filterName) {
  let result;
  const findValue = (data, filterName) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
      const current = data[i];
      if (current.name === filterName) {
        result = current.value;
        break;
      } else if (current.children) {
        findValue(current.children, filterName);
      }
    }
  }
  findValue(data, filterName);
  return result;
}

const data = [
  {
    name: 'a',
    value: 'b',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'c',
        value: 'd'
      }
    ]
  }
]

console.log(checkFilterValue(data, 'c'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) so you can stop iterating when you want to. It stops when callback function you provide returns true.
Additionally, some of the ifs can be simplified. You perform element.name check for elements with or without children, it seems - it can be placed separately.

```
checkFilterValue(group, currentFilterName) {
  return group.some((element, index) => { 
    if (element.name === currentFilterName) {
        this.returnedValue = element.value
        return true;
        }
    else if (element.children) {
        return this.checkFilterValue(element.children || this.filtersConfig[index + 1], currentFilterName);
      }
    else
        return false;
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where you have `element.children || this.filtersConfig[index + 1]` the value of `element.children` is always truthy, so the second expression will never be evaluated. This means `this.filtersConfig` does not play any role in your algorithm.

Since you indicate your code produces the expected results, and just want more elegant code, that part should be excluded from your code.

Here is a an arrow function that will find the value, but when it has done so, it will also stop iterating and recursing any further contrary to your code:

```
const checkFilterValue = (group, currentFilterName) =>
    group && group.some(element =>
        element.name === currentFilterName 
            ? (this.returnedValue = element.value, true) 
            : this.checkFilterValue(element.children, currentFilterName)
    );
```

Comment: can the method directly return the `element.value` without the assigned variable?

Comment: Sure. Did you try? It is not that hard to change the code above to achieve that. Have a go at it... Hint: use `findIndex` instead of `some` and do something with the result. Note that follow-up questions should really be posted as new questions.

Answer (score 0):

AnonymousSBs answers is pretty neat, but both of you have code that is not strictly necessary, he encapsulates the recursive part while I choose not o. The recursive approach, in any case, is probably the best one.

```
function checkFilterValue(group, currentFilterName) {
    for (let i = 0, element; element = group[i]; i++) {

        // use "return" to cancel loop early and return value
        // no need for else clause or break
        if (element.name === currentFilterName) {
            return this.returnedValue = element.value
        }

        // now we need to check if there are childern
        // not sure what filterConfig is, though, you may want to test this
        // index propably is the depth, and not the index of the loop
        let children = element.children || this.filtersConfig[i + 1]
        if (children) {
            return this.checkFilterValue(children, currentFilterName)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on where I’m missing return statements? My function with either return the value, or undefined (the default value of my result variable) also, using return in a for loop will exit the for loop, but will also exit the function, and OP might want to do some more stuff after the for loop, but before function end.

Comment: @AnonymousSB I'm sorry, your code seems fine now, I must have checked a previous version of your code where the recursion did not work due to the missing return statement at the recursive call.

Comment: @AnonymousSB About the second point; I generally hold of the opinion of breaking functions down as far as possible. Small functions are reusable, more comfortable for others to copy and importantly also to test.
In any case, one could add more code in my code at infront of the first return statement.